# Help me choose ML method

Tags: predictive-models

I have a dataset with a lot of classes with varying amounts of data points in them, from 1075 to 1 with an average of ~19.5.

Each datapoint has information of a subset of labels where the correct one is among them.
Apart from this, each data point has a large number of features.
For training and testing the correct label is also given.

So far I have been testing SVMs but I don't know how to implement the information from the subsets.

Any tips are greatly welcomed

Comment: It is hard to understand the structure of your dataset from your description. Can you give an example, indicating what is being predicted, and what the potential predictors are.

Comment: It is an SRL problem, so the data consists of words, their role (as in if it's a verb, adjective, etc.) the relationship to their syntactic head. What I want to predict is the words' semantic role in the sentence, what is the word doing in the sentence. 

ex. "Jack swam across the lake". Here "the lake" is the role "place". Each sentence comes with a subset of possible roles as explained earlier.

There is much research on this topic, but I'm looking for an easy implementation eg via sklearn.